# Can I inject proxies in front of Blueprint services published by other bundles?

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi

We are using `Karaf` and a number of `OSGI Blueprint services` to implement a system.

Is it possible to make a `"BundleListener"` type of bundle that, when present in the `OSGI` container, decorates our `Blueprint services` with a proxy so bundles referring these services will call the proxy instead?

(I guess this could be accomplished either by somehow adding the proxy in front of the service already in the Service Registry, or by changing the reference obtained by the referring bundle - `ServiceTracker.addingService` style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do these hacks is to use the service hooks in the OSGi core framework. The hooks allow you to remove a service from the view of one or more bundles. You can then register another service that proxies the first service and that is not removed from the bundle's view.

Existing:

```
  +----------+              +----------+
  | register |------<|------| using    |
  +----------+              +----------+
```

Proxied

```
  +----------+         hide +----------+
  | register |------<|-+--X-| using    |---|>---+ proxied
  +----------+         |    +----------+        |
                       |                        |
                       |    +----------+        |
                       +----|  manager |--------+
                            +----------+
```

Though at first a bit odd, this "remove from view" capability allows you to control in detail what service a bundle is exposed to while keeping the overall complexity minimal. See chapter 55 in the OSGi 5.0.0 Core. Section 55.3.1 details this proxying.

`<soapbox>`

I call these things hacks because proxies this way have bad runtime temporal ordering qualities. If your manager bundle (the one that hides and creates the proxies) is started later than the bundle using the service you're in trouble since the using bundle is temporarily exposed to the non-proxied service.

Though there are ways you to solve start ordering this problem, they all basically suck since you now have a undeclared (ordering) dependency. It is thus MUCH better to ensure that the bundle that uses the proxy has a special dependency, like another service type or a special service property. Since the dependency then is explicit, you have no more worries about ordering, the temporal dependency has now become an ordinary service dependency problem which is handled very well by DS and other service managers in OSGi.

Using property/other type to proxy

```
  +----------+              +----------+    proxied=true
  | register |              | using    |---|>---+ 
  +----------+              +----------+        |
        |                                       |
        |                   +----------+        |
        +-----------<|------|  manager |--------+
                            +----------+
```

You obviously do not want to modify the bundle that registers the service nor the bundle that uses the service since this would kill the whole idea of a reusable aspect. The programmers of the registering/using bundles should be blissfully unaware of the manager's scheme. So how do you se the filter on the using bundle?

If you use Declarative Services (DS), then you're in luck! With DS you can set a filter on a service reference through Configuration Admin with the 'target.' configuration property. So the manager bundle sees a service to be proxied, it registers a second service with a special property (e.g. 'proxied=true'). The using bundle then has a filter  set through Configuration Admin DS' target reference property like '(proxied=*)'.

`</soapbox>`

Comment: Another approach to solve the start order issue might be to use capabilities. The bundle that uses the service could depend on a "service proxy" capability and the manager bundle could offer the capability.

Comment: @Peter This sounds like the thing I need, thanks! The proxying "aspect" bundle would be part of our platform/framework bundle set so quite ok to let it start earlier with help from start levels or similar. I'll look at your Configuration Admin suggestion. Where does the code live that assigns the service filter? Does it only work with DS:target and not with Blueprint's filter property?

Comment: @peterkriens ,  I didn't get your solution for ordering issue. can you  point me to a more detailed document/guide please? And may I know if the same solution is possible with blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

Although not implemented as a proxy, a Blueprint Interceptor might do what you want; you can intercept method invocations before or after the call to the original bean. I assume this is what you'd be doing with your proxy anyway. The Aries Blueprint implementation in Karaf should definitely support interceptors. However, I can't find good documentation or examples outside the Aries source itself, which makes this answer less useful than I'd hoped!

Comment: Thanks! I don't find any mention of interceptors in the Blueprint spec. Do they allow a bundle to add interceptors to another bundle's services?

Comment: I believe it was an extension to the Aries implementation of the Blueprint spec which they were hoping to submit to the next version of the Blueprint spec, but I don't know if that ever happened. Sometimes these things get standardised under a different name. They definitely work cross-bundle; the examples I could see were all in the blueprint-core bundle, but intended to apply to user bundles. For example, there's a QuiesceInterceptor class. They implement the Interceptor interface, but I didn't immediately see how they were registered.

Comment: I think that Aries actually turns your interceptors into proxy classes for you under the covers, and getting proxies right can be complex, so in principle it could save you hassle. In practice I'm not sure if it's ever been tried by user code.